# Create a subscription returns error Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, subscription, microsoft-graph-mail

I've been trying to create a subscription to a user's outlook mail inbox using Microsoft Graph.

I've defined all the necessary grants/rights on Azure AD. (`Mail.Read`, `Mail.ReadWrite`)

My `create_subscription` method is defined below:

```
def create_subscription(
        self,
        change_type: str,
        notification_url: str,
        resource: str,
        expiration_datetime: datetime,
        client_state: str = None,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> Response:
       
        if isinstance(expiration_datetime, datetime):
            expiration_datetime = format_time(expiration_datetime, is_webhook=True)

        data = {
            "changeType": change_type,
            "notificationUrl": notification_url,
            "resource": resource,
            "expirationDateTime": expiration_datetime,
            "clientState": client_state,
        }
        data.update(kwargs)
        response = self._client._post(self._client.base_url + "subscriptions", json=data)
        return response
```

The `_post` call redirects it to the `_post()` function:

```
def _post(self, url, **kwargs):
        return self._request("POST", url, **kwargs)
def _request(self, method, url, headers=None, **kwargs) -> Response:
        _headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
        }
        _headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + self.token["access_token"]
        if headers:
            _headers.update(headers)
        if "Content-Type" not in _headers:
            _headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        return self._parse(requests.request(method, url, headers=_headers, **kwargs))
```

When I call the `create_subscription` function:

```
client.webhooks.create_subscription( "created", 
"https://****-**-***-**-***.in.ngrok.io/notification/listen",                                

"/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
"2022-10-28T10:00:00.0000000Z", "SecretClientState" )
```

It throws the following error:

```
microsoftgraph.exceptions.BadRequest: 
{
  'error': {
    'code': 'InvalidRequest', 
    'message': 'Subscription validation request failed. Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validation request.', 
    'innerError': {
      'date': '2022-10-25T05:30:53', 
      'request-id': '53763195-88e8-441f-b3e0-1520587f6ba1', 
      'client-request-id': '53763195-88e8-441f-b3e0-1520587f6ba1'
    }
  }
}
```

How would I be required to go about validating the subscription; because as per my understanding, when the subscription is created, my notification URL should respond with a '200 OK' status_code, along with the value of the `validationtoken` query string parameter as a plain-text response.

Would really appreciate it if someone could guide me through the entire process. Thanks!

Comment: Could you confirm that your notification endpoint received the validation request? The response on validation request is the same string that was sent in the validationToken query parameter

Comment: This is what I got whilst inspecting on ngrok: 

Query Params:
validationToken Validation: Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 0a0b6c73-9b8d-44a9-9787-86214cacea6f

(502 Bad Gateway)